# peeping tom(as an adjective)

Tags: grammar, word-choice

Let's say you are giving an opinion on some girls about them as peeping tom.

> ''Although girls are known to be demure, they can be **peeping toms** sometimes.

Is this grammatical?

P.S:what I wanted to say is they also can spy on other guys intentionally, with sexual gratification.

Comment: Usually, 'peeping Tom' is written thus, 'Tom' being a proper name. It might seem odd to call a girl by a term for a spying man. Perhaps 'voyeuse' might be better. Or 'female peeping Tom'.

Comment: Can you try to re-title your question to make it neater and more grammatical? That's a rather confusing title. P.S. It should be `P.S.`, not `P.s:`.

Comment: Thx for the correction, that's what I like it here. If you go to other sites, they don't have much organizational skills or systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"peeping toms" is a noun in your sentence. It's like, "Although girls are considered to have greater verbal abilities than math abilities, they can be mathematicians sometimes." It's not like, "Although girls are, on average, shorter than boys, they can be tall sometimes."

Comment: So what is your alternative word for this?

Comment: Sorry that I wasn't clear. I'm saying that you are using the term "peeping Toms" correctly. You don't need an alternative. Except Michael Harvey is correct. Tom is a proper name that is capitalized: "peeping Toms". I don't have any problem with using a male term for a female. It seems that suits your intent.

Comment: Hmm ok. I bet you a nickel that we don't usually hear this on a daily basis, and how I have used it is a matter of style, a bit unique as I put it.